# Access denied BigQuery: no OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I am getting an error on a Google Cloud function that I didn't have previously when launching the service a few months ago.

> "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive
>   scope was found"

As far as I know I am not trying to access Google Drive in my node.js script and the BigQuery query also doesn't need access to Google Drive. I have looked at the service account for this function and it has G Suite access. Can anyone shed light on why I am getting this error and what can I do to fix it?